# Two Tables Two Relationships ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I had this doubt this morning and couldn't get an answer. I hope someone can help me.

I have two tables (T1 & T2)

```
T1 
-> Id (P)
-> InstanceId (U)
-> ObjectId (U)
-> Name

T2 
-> Id (P)
-> InstanceId (F) (Foreign key for T1.InstanceId)
-> ObjectId (F) (Foreign key for T1.InstanceId)
-> Grade
```

I need to join these two tables using both the relationships and display the details of both tables using linq.

I have used this linq query but don't know how to return both tables, if i select t1 and t2 from this query, then ObjectId reference is not used (i.e t12)?

How can i solve this. I need to use both the relationships and wants to get both tables values.

LINQ:

```
var result = from t1 in db.T1 
             join t2 in db.T2 on t1.InstanceId equals t2.InstanceId 
             join t12 in db.T2 on t2.ObjectId equals t12.ObjectId 
             select t1;
```

Comment: None of the tags seems relevant to the question. Which ORM are you using? EF? You should add relations to your mapping, not try to join entities after the fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `new` keyword.

[join clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx)

```
var result =
        from t1 in db.T1
        join t2 in db.T2 on new { ObjectId : t1.ObjectId , InstanceId = t1.InstanceId} equals
                            new { ObjectId : t2.ObjectId , InstanceId = t2.InstanceId}
        select new
        {
            t1,
            t2
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @Neer, This is exactly what i need. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
   var x = context.T1.Where(t => t.Id == context.T2.InstanceId)
           .Select(x => new {
              t,
              t.Instance //use the related entity here)
            }).ToList();
```

'x' is an anonymous object you can use in your function.
t is the variable from T1, which is related to T2, in your class from T2 I would expect a parent to T1. That way you can use it in your anonymous object.

Comment: Thanks @RoelantM, but i need to use both InstanceId and ObjectId for joining. and i got the expected answer from NEER. Thanks again.